# How to remove jQuery slider values from submitting with GET form

Tags: jquery

With the followed code jQuery slider works fine and it's submitting with search form. I need to exclude it from url, because it's affecting my query. Can it be depending from a select field with the following syntax:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("select[name=is_range]").change(function(){
            var my_range = $("select[name=is_range]").val();

                $("#id-of-range-slider").hide(); //exclude field from url by default

                if (my_range == 'yes' ){
                    $("#id-of-range-slider").show(); // if yes option is selected show slider and accept in url 
                }

                else if(my_range == 'no') { 
                    $("#id-of-range-slider").hide(); // remove it if value is changed
                }   
    });
});
```

Apparently, it doesn't work with show/hide jQuery functions, because it only hiddes the field, not preventing it from submitting.

HTML slider:

```
<input type="text" name ="amount-range" id="amount" readonly>
<div id="slider-range"></div>
```

Javascript slider

```
jQuery(function() {
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
        range: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 100000,
        values: [ 5000, 25000 ],
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
           $( "#amount" ).val( "Between " + ui.values[ 0 ] + " and " +  ui.values[ 1 ] + " currency.");
        }
    });

    $( "#amount" ).val( "Between " + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) + " and " + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) + " currency." );
});
```

Any ideas, guys?

Comment: make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: I think I can use jQuery serialize function not including elements with display: none style or disabled attribute?

Comment: if you set a form item as disabled it won't be posted. Dysplay will not affect the event of posting the form

Comment: Actually, if I rework the form to refuse elements with state display:none, I will resolve my problem.

Comment: Any idea how I can set all elements with `display: none` to `disabled`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine with me. I couldn't thought of better solution still.

`$('#parent-div-id').children(":input").prop("disabled", true);`